# OracleDataSource connection caching - restarting connections?

Tags: oracle, caching, jdbc

Is it possible to set the Oracle connection cache to restart cached connections after a period of time?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new Universal Connection Pool. The class oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource has apropriate methods.

e.g.

```
void setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout(int timeToLiveConnectionTimeout)
                                    throws java.sql.SQLException
```

see javadoc at: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSource.html